# Canvas.DrawBitmap holds reference to bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, reference, ondraw, drawbitmap

In the following function:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap( bmp ,0,0,null);
    ViewCompat.postOnAnimationDelayed( this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
            c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

bmp is a regular image.

- I am drawing the bitmap on the canvas.
- On the next animation frame + 1 sec, I'm changing the content of the bitmap to blue.
- I'm **NOT** drawing the bitmap again.

The result is a blue screen.

Does this mean that the canvas is storing a reference to the bitmap?

Comment: turn off hardware acceleration

Comment: Hi pskink, 10x for your reply. I need the hardware acceleration but i will try and update.

Comment: Ok its working. disable hardware acceleration indeed solve the problem. However, as i said, i need the hardware acceleration so will have to find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve by your code?

Comment: i thought that on the next frame the bitmap already drawn so i can now use it for other purposes. for example, to prepare and draw it on other cells on grid.

Comment: so you need another Bitmap for that

Comment: that what i wanted to avoid, the creation of another bitmap.

Comment: so just call `Canvas#drawColor(Color.BLUE);` you dont need a `Bitmap` for that

Comment: it was just an example to show that changes in the bitmap affect the view even after the draw bitmap. assume that the same bitmap is being used to resize an image and draw it on another view. still, the first view will be affected also.